# How to make upsert call using Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am moving code from directly using ES API to Spring Data Elasticsearch. Couldn't find an equivalent of upsert in Spring ES UpdateQuery. Below is my current ES call.

```
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, type, id);
    indexRequest.source(jsonForIndex, XContentType.JSON);

    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(indexName, type, id);
    updateRequest.doc(jsonForUpdate, XContentType.JSON);
    updateRequest.upsert(indexRequest);
    updateRequest.fetchSource(true);
```

How to make this call using UpdateQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `UpdateQuery`.

Check out the tests in `ElasticsearchIntegrationTests.shouldDoUpsertIfDocumentDoesNotExist()` (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/main/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchIntegrationTests.java#L1609-L1630)